# Does Lift prevent HTTP response splitting?

Tags: security, http, scala, lift

When I manually add a header to a response in Lift with S.setHeader, do I have to check for newlines manually or is that done by the framework? This is needed to prevent [http response splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

Answer (score 0):

You should test it.  [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/#id=966) for Firefox allows you to modify http requests and view the response.  Setup a call to S.setHeader that accepts a get variable header.  Open tamper data within Firefox and it will log all requests. Visit a url like this: http://localhost/?header=1%0atest:+CRFL.  If tamper data shows a response header with a new server element of `test: CRLF`  then your platform is vulnerable to HTTP response splitting.

Comment: thanks, I was trying to avoid exactly that bit of work by asking here... I guess I am just lazy.

Comment: @Kim Stebel and thats how you get hacked.  When it comes to security the code can work and be very insecure.  The correct security  answer is almost never chosen.  The best thing that i can do is give you the tools to find it your self,  and in this case its painfully simple to test.

Comment: you're not getting hacked if you're not actually using setHeader anywhere in your app but are just curious...